# Algebraic function fields and algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, extension-field, algebraic-curves

At the moment, I try to understand the connection between an non-singular projective algebraic curve and an algebraic function field. The field $K$ is algebraically closed.

If an algebraic curve $\mathcal{C}$ is non-singular, then there exists a isomorphism between the points $P\in\mathcal{C}$ and the places of the function field $K(\mathcal{C})$ given by$$
 P\mapsto\mathcal{M}_P
$$where $\mathcal{M}_P$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_P$. Define $F_P=\mathcal{O}_P/\mathcal{M}_P$. Then the following holds:$$
[F_P:K]=1.
$$according to Stichtenoth's "Algebraic function fields and codes" (It should be noted I deduce this fact by the appendix and comparing definitions). But why? I am not a very smart person, but does this follow from the weak version of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz? If I can show that $F_P$ is a finitely-generated $K$-algebra, then I know that $F_P\cong K$, therefore I get the desired result.

I am grateful for any help!

Sincerely,
Hypertrooper

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_P$ itself is not a finitely generated $K$-algebra, but it is the localization of of a finitely generated $K$-algebra $A$. Thus, so is $F_P$, since $\mathcal{O}_P/\mathcal{M}_P=A/M$ for some maximal ideal  $M$ of $A$.